# How Do I Make A Selection Transparent Through The Object Behind It In Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency

[image]

I want to make all the white parts transparent. When I select one of the white shapes and make the fill nothing, then the shape doesn't have fill, but all it does is show the green behind it.

[image]

I am brand new to Illustrator and got this design from someone else, and I'm not sure how to do what I think should be a simple task. I tried researching about pathfinder and knockout groups, but I am having trouble getting this to work. Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your white shapes are above the green background. To make them transparent they need to be cut out from the green background.

Select all the art, both white and green, Expand it and click Pathfinder>Divide.

Ungroup the result.

Now when you delete a white shape it should be clipped out from the green, revealing the background..

Comment: Thank you Webster! This worked, although I had to tweak your instructions. I think I didn't ungroup at the end because it wasn't working. Anyway, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select all
2. Object > Compound Path > Make